# How to validate form_for elemets together with form_tag elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a `form_for` form to which I added custom fields using `*_tag` methods.

For normal `form_for` elements I have validation inside the model, however I am not sure what should I do with my `text_field_tag` elements.

What would be the most elegant way to validate those fields?

Code update:

```
<%= form_for(@member, :html => {:class => "generic-form"}) do |f| %>
    <% if @member.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@member.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this member from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @member.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label :username, "Username:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.label :password, "Password:" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= label_tag "repeatPassword", "Repeat password:" %>
  <%= password_field_tag "repeatPassword" %>
  <%= f.label :email, "Email:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <button type="submit" name="commit">Register</button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do those custom fields belong to some other model, or to no model at all? Could you post some sample code?

Comment: I added sample code. The `repeatPassword` field does not belong to any model, it is just there to check  if the password was typed right. What would be the most elegant way to check if it is not empty and matches the `:password` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an action which update/create a Member instance. In this action you could do something like this:

```
def update
  [...]
  if params[:repeatPassword] == params[:member][:password]
    @member.save
  else
    @member.errors.add('password', 'Passwords werent the same')
    redirect_to :action => :update, :id => params[:id]
  end
  [...]
end
```

Hope this Helps!